# how can i, using a while loop, output each character of the users input back to them individually?

Tags: linux, bash

[image]

I am writing a bash script which, uses an until loop to continuously ask the user to enter a 6 letter fruit until they enter a word with 6 letters. Uses a for loop to output the user’s chosen fruit back to them 10 times.

I am finding it difficult to use a while loop to output each character of the users chosen fruit on a new line.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your script to the question (select the resulting code block and use the `{}` button to format it as code)

Comment: Yes, please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, please post a script that actually produces the output you show and explain exactly what you are expecting. The script you show will only work for the specific word `banana`. It doesn't "loop continuously until they enter a word with 6 letters", it loops until they enter `banana`.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
fold -w 1 <<<"$fruit"
```

or, portably,

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$fruit" | fold -w 1
```

This would call the `fold` utility, which is a utility for folding long lines.  We give it `-w 1` to fold the lines after each character, creating the effect that you seem to want to have.

As you notice, this does not use a `while` loop.  If you are solving  some form of home assignment, and you *need* to use a `while` loop to pass it, then do this:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$fruit" | fold -w 1 |
while read -r character; do
    printf '%s\n' "$character"
done
```

This is portable to any POSIX-like shell and does not contain any bash-isms.

Then try finding a teacher that does not force you to solve problems using specific tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping a beginner!